# load from csv error on Neo4j - Unexpected end of input

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am running a simple command - > `LOAD CSV FROM "file:///csvjson.csv"` on **neo4j** browser.

The error I am getting:

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input:
>   expected whitespace, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS,
>   CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', '~', "<>", "!=", '<',
>   '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR or AS (line 1, column 36 (offset: 35))
>   "LOAD CSV FROM "file:///csvjson.csv""

I have tried many variations of this command and they do not work

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 12):

That is not a complete Cypher statement.

The `LOAD CSV` clause requires the `AS xxx` term, in order to know what variable name you want to use for each row of data. Also, the Cypher statement requires a `RETURN` clause, since it is currently just reading data (instead of writing).

Here is an example of a minimal legal statement that just returns each row of data:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///csvjson.csv" AS row
RETURN row
```

Comment: Helped me a lot! Thanks for the detailed answer!